# Typescript - reading or writing to maps that are part of a list with different types of maps

Tags: typescript

I have a component where I am passing a list that consists of 2 types:

```
events: List<OrderEvent | PackageEvent>
```

They both have property `packageId` defined:

```
export interface OrderEvent extends ImmutableMap<{
  departmentId?: DepartmentIdType,
  orderId?: number,
  createdAt: ISODateTimeString,
  type: EventType,
  data?: AnyData
  eventTime: ISODateTimeString
  role?: string
  packageId?: string
}> {
}

export interface PackageEvent extends ImmutableMap<{
  createdAt: ISODateTimeString,
  type: EventType,
  name?: string,
  packageId?: string
}> {
}
```

I would like to iterate over that list of maps and read and write properties from each map be it `OrderEvent` or `PackageEvent`, so for example:

```
const events  = consignmentEvents as List<OrderEvent | PackageEvent>

events.first().get('packageId')
```

If I do that I get a typescript error:

> Object is of type 'unknown'.

Or if I do this:

```
events.first<OrderEvent | PackageEvent>().get('packageId')
```

I get a Typescript error:

> This expression is not callable. Each member of the union type has
> signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each
> other.

How can I then create a list of different types of maps and read or write their properties?

Answer (score 0):

When working with Typescript unions, you usually have to use one of the different ways of [type narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html).

In this case, you could loop through each of these maps and narrow them down to either an `OrderEvent` or a `PackageEvent`.

One example using [in operator narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) is the following.

```
for (const event of events) {
  if ('orderId' in event) { // Typescript knows it's an `OrderEvent`
    console.log(event.orderId); // We can access its fields
  } else { // A `PackageEvent`
    console.log(event.name);
  }
}
```

Also, I see your types have a `type` field. If that's something that distinguishes them you can use it to narrow the union type. Something like the following.

```
...
if (event.type === OrderEventPackage) {
  // We know it's an `OrderEvent` but typescript doesn't
  const orderEvent = event as OrderEvent; // We need to do a type assertion
}
```

Type assertions can be dangerous because they tell typescript to stop type checking that particular variable and let us do the work of knowing everything is safe.
It's always better (although not always possible) to let typescript do the work.

In the case that the `type` event is used to differentiate them, you could just it the literal that represents the type. For example.

```
export interface OrderEvent extends ImmutableMap<{
  ...
  type: 'OrderEvent',
  ...
}> {}

export interface PackageEvent extends ImmutableMap<{
  ...
  type: 'PackageEvent',
  ...
}> {}
```

Now you could narrow the union by the value of the `type` field.

```
...
if (type === 'OrderEvent') {
  // Typescript knows the type is OrderEvent and we can access its fields
} else {
  // Typescript knows the type is PackageEvent
}
```